# Magento 2 How to remove template in checkout page?

Tags: magento2.3, template, checkout-page

We have a custom template file and want to display it on all the pages except the checkout page. However, it shows even in checkout page. We have used the below code in our theme `default.xml.`

```
<container name="footer.newsletter" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="home-newsletter textcenter white-text" after="home.customers">
                <block class="Magento\Newsletter\Block\Subscribe" name="form.subscribe.home" template="Magento_Newsletter::subscribe.phtml" ifconfig="newsletter/general/active"/>
            </container>
```

Can anyone please help me on how to remove it from checkout page?

Answer (score 3):

Add your block in `default.xml` and in `checkout_index_index.xml` write below code:

```
<referenceBlock name="form.subscribe.home" remove="true" />
```

Hope it solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

In more recent versions of Magento2, the remove method is now:

```
<referenceBlock name="block_name" remove="true"/>
```

> **Example**: Remove newsletter in block on page and footer links block on page

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
     <referenceBlock name="form.subscribe" remove="true" />
     <referenceBlock name="footer_links" remove="true" />
</body>
</page>
```

The **steps I** mention above is the shortest process for you to  Remove Block in Layout in Magento 2.